# How to Return Camera View Back to the Origin?

Tags: 3d-view

I know this may seem like a stupid idea, but the view, camera, whatever you call it (the view you see while flying around in the viewport) is very far from the grid. When I try to zoom to get closer, it eventually stops scrolling in. Is there some way for me to instantly bring the camera view back to the origin?

Answer (score 14):

View > Align view > **Center Cursor and View All** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

OR

Select an object from Outliner and:
View > Align view > **View Selected** <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>

Comment: Center Cursor and View All doesn't jump back to the origin, it jumps to the center point of the contents of the scene.